# How does Carto make it possible to interact with elements on their tiles? Can I do the same with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, carto

I was looking at [this Carto Map](https://metabolismofcities.carto.com/builder/2cbb6de4-fab5-11e6-8bb7-0e3a376473ab/embed). You can click on a building and it shows some extra information about it.

Then I noticed that these buildings weren't added as individual polygons or something like that, but instead are part of generated tiles that has been added to the map. [Here is a an example of a single tile](https://cartocdn-gusc-c.global.ssl.fastly.net/metabolismofcities/api/v1/map/metabolismofcities@7a531cb2@5af9eaafc1a3c12f118f8b095be791eb:1523352285209/1/14/14789/10053.png).

If you look at the code these tiles have the `leaflet-tile` class, so it seems like Carto are using Leaflet for adding the tiles to the map.

But how is it possible that there is interaction? I don't think it's possible to interact with PNG files like this, so what *is* going on?

I have a large dataset of buildings. If I add them to a map using Leaflet the map gets really slow, so I would like to use something like [Mapnik](https://mapnik.org/) to generate the tiles and make things a lot faster. But as far as I know I will then lose interactivity, which is a real shame.

Is there a way to use Leaflet to add tiles rather than features and keep interactivity with the features that are generated onto the tiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic is called **UTFGrid** and it was developed by Mapbox. It is basically ["an encoding scheme that efficiently encodes interactivity data for map tiles"](https://blog.mapbox.com/how-interactivity-works-with-utfgrid-3b7d437f9ca9). [According to the documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec/blob/master/1.1/utfgrid.md), for each map tile there is a json storing each pixel values as long strings. Then you can easily retrieve the information when interacting with that map tile pixel.

You can check for yourself in the console:

[image: grid jsons]

Builder and CARTO.js maps are rendered using raster (image) tiles. So the tiles are built as sandwiches (basemap + data + style) on the server (backend), and then "painted" on the client/browser (frontend) everytime you pan or zoom and there is no caching involved. [Vector rendering](https://www.maptiler.com/news/2019/02/what-are-vector-tiles-and-why-you-should-care/), on the other hand, fetches everything and then you can interact, style and so on on the browser. Mapbox (and everything built on top such as CARTO VL or Deck GL/Kepler), Google, OL... all are already using this technology because it produces a faster and smooth experience.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Is [this repository](https://github.com/danzel/Leaflet.utfgrid) something I could use in combination with Leaflet?

Comment: There are several plugins in Leaflet, searching in google and github should return many results. Also I former colleague of mine [built this client](https://github.com/cartodb/zera) some time ago.